# Rails + Bootstrap: How to iterate over collection of items with multiple items per row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

When I want to display a collection of things in a Rails view, I usually do something like this:

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6"><%= item.attribute1 %></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6"><%= item.attribute2 %></div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I want to do something different though. I want to display the first 2 items in the first row, the next 2 in the second row etc. Conceptually like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-3"><%= item.attribute1 %></div> <!-- first item in collection -->
  <div class="col-xs-3"><%= item.attribute2 %></div> <!-- first item in collection -->

  <div class="col-xs-3"><%= item.attribute1 %></div> <!-- second item in collection -->
  <div class="col-xs-3"><%= item.attribute2 %></div> <!-- second item in collection -->
</div>
```

I feel like this shouldn't be too difficult, but I'm not sure how to get it done. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [in_groups_of method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-in_groups_of) like:

```
<% @items.in_groups_of(2) do |item1, item2| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6"><%= item1.attribute1 %></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6"><%= item1.attribute2 %></div>
    <% if item2 %> <%# To take care of odd groups %>
      <div class="col-xs-6"><%= item2.attribute1 %></div>
      <div class="col-xs-6"><%= item2.attribute2 %></div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

With `in_groups_of` you can group the `@items` collection in a group of 2 items each and iterate over it.

**UPDATE**

`@items` is generated using `gem tire` and is actually type of `Tire::Results::Collection` class. In that case, you need to first convert it to an array and then apply `in_groups_of` method on it as shown below:

```
<% @items.to_ary.in_groups_of(2) do |item1, item2| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6"><%= item1.attribute1 %></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6"><%= item1.attribute2 %></div>
    <% if item2 %> <%# To take care of odd groups %>
      <div class="col-xs-6"><%= item2.attribute1 %></div>
      <div class="col-xs-6"><%= item2.attribute2 %></div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what I want. `@items` are search results from Tire, so the problem I'm running into is this: `undefined method 'in_groups_of' for #<Tire::Results::Collection:0x00000104919150>`. Any idea why I can't call this on search results as-is?

Comment: Hmm.. As you didn't specify in the question that `@items` is generated  using gem `tire` and is actually type of `Tire::Results::Collection` class, I assumed that its like a collection of a normal Rails model of class `ActiveRecord::Relation`. It seems like `Tire::Results::Collection` doesn't have any provision for grouping records.

Comment: Try something like `@items.to_ary.in_groups_of(2)` and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Ah I see, that was my fault. Your `to_ary` solution worked, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `in_groups_of` provided by ActiveSupport

```
<% @items.in_groups_of(2) do |item1, item2| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6"><%= item1.attribute1 %></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6"><%= item1.attribute2 %></div>
    <% if item2 %>
      <div class="col-xs-6"><%= item2.attribute1 %></div>
      <div class="col-xs-6"><%= item2.attribute2 %></div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I am just curious, how does your answer differs from mine?

Comment: @KirtiThorat the OP wanted a way to show 2 items from the collection within a single row but conceptually, our answers do not differ. I should have refreshed prior to posting mine and just commented on your. I apologize.